# Changing Text using JS .getElementsByClassName: Class Names are the Same, and I only want to change the text of one

Tags: javascript

I'm not exactly sure how to word this, but I am using Javascript to change text. I am using Javascript on the site Quizlet. As you can see, there are two columns: terms and definitions. As of now, the script changes both when I only want it to change the term list. Here's a video, too: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ly3askpLQjzXeCMx9Mk9iVpSEXCw6i25/view

[image]

Works, but changes both:

```
var myClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("ProseMirror");

for (var i = 0; i < myClasses.length; i++) {
  myClasses[i].innerHTML = "new content";
  }
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
var myClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("WordList");.document.getElementsByClassName("ProseMirror");

for (var i = 0; i < myClasses.length; i++) {
  myClasses[i].innerHTML = "new content";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to find a `.ProseMirror` element only when it's inside a `.WordList` element, you can use a CSS selector for that with `querySelector`:

```
const element = doucment.querySelector(".WordList .ProseMirror");
element.innerHTML = "new content";
```

That finds the first element with the class `ProseMirror` that's also inside an element with class `WordList`.

I don't think you want a list of matches, but if you did, you'd use `querySelectorAll` (which returns a `NodeList` of all matches) instead of `querySelector` (which returns the first matching element).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Oddly enough, though, the text is not changing.

Comment: @zbush548 - Well, I was just taking your class names as read. Are you sure `.WordList` is correct? It's hard to read a screenshot (*always* best to provide that information as text, not just an image) but I think I'm seeing `.WordSide` not `.WordList` for the outer one.

Comment: @zbush548 - Great! :-) Separately, I think you need to call a ProseMirror method to update the contents, rather than directly manipulating the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get the elements with multiple classes.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.WordList.ProseMirror');
```